# Vec::chunks borrows data and I can't return chunks

Tags: parsing, vector, rust

I have a `.txt` file with some text. For example

```
a
b
...
z
```

And I wanna get `Vec<Vec<&str>>` of chunks with size `N` or something equal (actually, code below gives me `<Vec<&[&str]>>` and I don't really see difference. I suppose `&[&str]` is "borrowed" `Vec[&str]` wanna google.)

Here is my attempt:

```
fn read_input()<'a>() -> Vec<&'a[&'a str]> {
    let input = include_str!(r"PATH\input.txt");
    let lines_info = input.lines().collect::<Vec<&'a str>>();
    let chunked_lines_info = lines_info.chunks(7).collect::<Vec<&'a [&'a str]>>();

    chunked_lines_info 
}
```

Basically, I think I know WHY it is: `chunks` borrows value from `lines_info`, but 'lines_info' freed at the end of function but I try to return something that borrows freed data. I tried `.clone()` `lines_info` before get chunks (the most dummy way) but it never works.

I tried something (better, I suppose) like this:

```
fn read_input<'a>() -> Vec<[&'a str; 7]> {
    let input = include_str!(r"PATH\input.txt");
    let info = input.lines().array_chunks::<7>().collect();
    info 
}
```

But it gives me "unstable library" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `lines_info().chunks()` borrows from `lines_info` and cannot outlive it. You need to `collect()` the chunks. Also, you can use `'static` instead of `'a`:

```rust
fn read_input() -> Vec<Vec<&'static str>> {
    let input = include_str!(r"PATH\input.txt");
    let lines_info = input.lines().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let chunked_lines_info = lines_info
        .chunks(7)
        .map(|v| v.iter().copied().collect())
        .collect();

    chunked_lines_info
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So... Am I forced to create iterator with copied elements? Sounds like I'm doing "extra" work here.

Comment: @Eugene `copied()` is not expensive. It is just because `iter()` gives references.